# Select the first n values of columns in a row without using select

Tags: excel, vba

Hey I just found a great code on this site which allows you to dynamically select the n bottom values of columns in a row. with the following code:

```
Dim LastRow, a As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

Range("K" & LastRow - 2 & ":K" & LastRow).Copy
```

My code above selects the 2 values at the bottom. Is there any way I can select the two top values of columns in  a cell? I tried to do it brainless by modifying my code to

```
Dim LastRow, a As Long

firstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlDown).Row

Range("K" & firstRow + 2 & ":K" & firstRow).Copy
```

However, that doesn't seem to do the job. Furthermore, in my row columns where I want to select the first 10 values there is a string/text above, how do I deal with that?

Comment: Is the row number with the "string/text above" known or constant? One approach here is to use `Resize`, perhaps paired with `Offset`.

Comment: it is a fixed string

Comment: What I meant - is the row *number* known or can it change?

Comment: The row number will not be changed, but I want  the code to allow that  the first column number can change index.

Comment: Could you explain this using a practical example e.g.: Cell `K5` contains "Text". I want to create a reference to (copy) the two cells below it, in this case, "K6:K7".

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim RowsToCopy As Long

' First row is 2 if there is a header text, else 1.
Firstrow = 2
RowsToCopy = 2

' Copy 2 rows starting at 'Firstrow'
Range("K" & Firstrow & ":K" & Firstrow + (RowsToCopy - 1)).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testFirstTwoRows()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, firstR As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet

   firstR = sh.Range("K1").End(xlDown).row

   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("K1:K" & firstR - 1)) > 0 Or _
                                                        firstR = sh.rows.count Then
        firstR = 1
   End If
   
   Range("K" & firstR & ":K" & firstR + 1).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: @S Jensen: Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?